# Boundaries of the visible gamut in a CIE color space

Tags: color-space, lab-color-space

I would like to know if there is any mathematical way to determine the boundaries of the **visible spectrum/gamut** in a CIE color space (*e.g.* Lab, XYZ). Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a formula to check if a given point is within a defined visible gamut?

Comment: I'm looking for a formula which gives me the limit of the visible gamut. But having something which allows me to check if a point is within the gamut will also solve my problem.

Comment: I've been doing quite a bit of research around CIELab recently and nothing stands out in my mind for validating colors in the Lab Gamut. We are able to model CIELab as a 3D volume so there *must* be a way, but I have not seen it.

Answer (score 2):

mmm... this seems to be a not-so-good formulation of a valid question.

As boscarol pointed it out, the boundary of the human gamut is determined by the `"color matching functions"` that you will decide to use, which refer to the type of `"standard observer"` you need, i.e., `2° (1931, often used)` or `10° (1964, a bit rare)`, or something new like `cvrl.org proposed 2006 observers (2° or 10°)`

To get the points in the `CIE xy 1931 chromaticity diagram` that you put in your message, you have to apply the conversion `XYZ to Yxy` to the 3 color matching functions `x_bar, y_bar and z_bar` that you will find in the standard's observer CMF data, for ex. here: http://www.cvrl.org/ then check `CMFs` and pick one file to download.

The coordinates of the `spectrum locus` (the limits of the human observer's gamut) are, for each wavelength, the `xy` coordinates that you will obtain from the `XYZ to Yxy` transformation, which goes, for ex. in Python 2.7:

```
def XYZ_to_Yxy(X,Y,Z):
    """for each wavelength of the CMFs, you will replace X, Y, Z by x_bar, y_bar, z_bar here..."""

    x = X/(X+Y+Z)
    y = Y/(X+Y+Z)

    return Y,x,y
```

EDIT I forgot to mention that the `spectrum locus` is only the curve part of the limit. The straight line at the bottom is called the `"line of purples"` and to get its xy coordinates in the diagram, you can simply trace a straight line between the point that corresponds to `380 nm` (blue-violet) and the one for `730 nm` (extreme red).

The bad point of this technique is that it will only give you limits of `chromaticity` (2D), while a real device or so gamut should be in `3D`

To solve this problem is more complicated, there are some algorithms availlable to plot a gamut in the `CIE L*a*b* color space` for example, which are described somewhere on this website:

http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?LabGamutDisplayHelp.html

good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Even though I'm no longer working on that project, the subject still interests me and your answer is very helpful!

Comment: I added the line of purples